# Initramfs unpacking failed: no cpio magic - How to start my PC?

Tags: linux, fedora

I have recently installed Fedora 39 and when trying to boot I found this error:

```
[   0.533164] Initramfs unpacking failed: no cpio magic
/init: error while loading shared libraries: libsystemd-shared-254.5-2.fc39.so: cannot open shared boject file: No such file or directory
```

But now I have booted it correctly. But this problem is not new. I was using Kubuntu before and then switched to Fedora 38 and then Fedora 39. This problem is still not solved. So I don't think it is a problem related to Fedora. It frequently happens with my PC. But this is the first time I encountered this error message. This problems happens in these two ways:

- If I turn on System, Monitor is not turning on.
- Sometimes Monitor turns on, but gets distorted and paused after using it for a few hours.

Here is the specs of my PC.
OS: Fedora 39
RAM: 4GB
Storage: 1TB

Comment: You have extracted two lines out of the boot log, and now they have no context. You need to show such error messages in context, with the surrounding messages (e.g +/- 10 lines).